# Are p values produced by `p.adjust(method="fdr")` actually probabilities?

Tags: r, p-value, false-discovery-rate

I've been trying to clarify for myself how to interpret the p values produced by p.adjust with method="fdr/BH".

I'm aware of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323817/r-unexpected-results-from-p-adjust-fdr and [Multiple hypothesis testing with FDR in R - FDRtool and p.adjust](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111453/multiple-hypothesis-testing-with-fdr-in-r-fdrtool-and-p-adjust) and other similar discussions online, e.g.  https://support.bioconductor.org/p/49864/

However, from this it's not clear how to interpret the values produced. It seems like the values this method produces are not really probabilities anymore - as are the case with other 'adjusted' p values, e.g. via Holm method. Rather, it's that if choose to reject null hypotheses where the p_fdr < X, then we are maintaining a false discovery rate < X. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Could you help us understand the implicit distinction you make between a (presumably long term, hypothetical) *rate*, as in "false discovery rate," and a *probability*?

Comment: Hmmm. I suppose I'm getting confused because this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Benjamini–Hochberg_procedure implies the BH procedure controls the familywise FDR rate provided you reject all tests which don't meet the criterion. But I wasn't clear that the values produced then related to a probability for the specific null hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

By my understanding, the question is about what these corrected p-values actually mean. It would be nice to have, like in a case of testing a single hypothesis, a straight forward meaning such as the probability of observing a given outcome assuming that the null hypothesis is true.

I believe that you are correct in your assertions. In case of the BH correction and other corrections based on controlling the False Discovery Rate , correcting the p-values is just a construct to control the FDR. The same way other methods based on FWER control only serve that purpose and p-values loose their original meaning.

I would argue that the process of making and reporting the correction is here out of habit/ for consistency. It is simple for people to interpret a test result based on a p-value and this way they can keep the way of evaluating statistical significance and make a good judgment.

Comment: I think I agree with this answer until the last sentence; I'm not convinced that interpreting the adjusted p-values, after they lose their quantitative meaning outside of maintaining an FDR/expected FDR, is simple or conducive to good judgement.

Comment: It took me a long time to realize a major potential advantage of adjusting `p` to get it so that an alpha-level test against the adjusted p maintains an FDR or FWER... it is so that readers can each apply their own threshold to a single set of results. I'm not sure this outweighs the negatives of adjusting p-values.